# How can I read data from package.json into an index. Pug file?

Tags: json, node.js, pug

I'm trying to pull in some simple data from package.json like name and description into pug to render in the title and meta description tags.

I don't have any server code, just client side. I'll be compiling things, kind of how a static site generator compiles markdown etc into a static site.

I tried doing `-var json = require (./package.json);` but pug didn't recognize require.

How might I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "static site thing"?  Are you just using Pug on the client and no server-side code.  If there's server-side code, then show us the server-side code.  If only client-side code, then show us that code.  Questions about code MUST show the relevant code.  With this little info to go on, it is not possible to answer this question - we could only make wild guesses what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have installed PUG.

Define views/index.pug (example):

```
html
  body
    h1 Project name: #{name}
    h1 Project license: #{license}
```

Render index.pug

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8'));
  res.render('index', obj)
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!')
})
```

In async way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('package.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('index', JSON.parse(data));
  });
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: I'm not using express, just pug. Building a static site thing.

Comment: You'd need to add javascript file which would load your local package.json and would update page with data you want. With Express it's much easier.